# What is the purpose of hdfs dfs -test /dir_name?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am reading a code and found too many use of `hdfs dfs -test /dir_name`.
I am curious about how does it execute its operations.

Comment: Read the documentation: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#test

Answer (score 1):

The command contacts the NameNode of the Hadoop cluster and returns a status code of 0 if that path exists, otherwise non-zero if it doesn't.

[**Docs**](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#test)

[**Source methods**](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.java#L1722-L1784)

Answer (score 1):

Returns 0 if that path exists, and non-zero if the path does not exist